# Animation Nodes: How to cut copy and paste functions

Tags: animation-nodes

For example I want a function who is
cossinus from less infinite to zero (time info)
then square root frome zero to 100
then end here.

How could I combine this ?

More explanations:

I got a funtion cossinus who use time frame for x. I want to cut it for the x value from less infinite to 0.
Then I have an other function who is square root and have frame time for x. I want to cut it for the x values from 0 to 100. Then I want to paste both cut to make one function.

Comment: Hello, it seems the title of your question and its body are not asking for the same thing. Could you elaborate a bit more on what you are trying to do ?

Comment: I got a funtion cossinus who use time frame for x. I want to cut it for the x value from less infinite to 0 (sorry I forget the "less" in he first description). Then I have an other function who is square root and have frame time for x. I want to cut it for the x values from 0 to 100. Then I want to paste both cut to make one function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a *switch* node and a *compare* node to evaluate the input x.

[image]